# Flask: use render_template or send_static_file?

Tags: python, flask

As the title states, I am creating a website using Flask and I am not sure the difference between those two functions in terms of displaying my page/HTML file.

Answer (score 1):

From [1], send_static_file() serves files from the static directory.  render_template() grabs templates from the templates/ directory, and (as the name shows) renders the template with information and serves it to the browser.

If you are planning to use static files,  use url_for()  [2]

[1] - https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/

[2] - https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/static/